# Microsoft Graph API - how to only get members of a group with enabled accounts?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get all the members of a particular group in MS Graph API, but I only want users to be returned if their accounts are enabled (i.e. they are able to sign in).

You can get *all* enabled users with this query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled eq true`. All members of a group can be returned with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id-here/members`.

I haven't found any way to combine the two though, to return all members of a group whose accounts are enabled? Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

To list all members of a group who are users and have account enabled set to true, you should first [list transitive members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the group, then use Odata cast and filter to get the data. Your request should look like this:

> GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/transitivemembers/microsoft.graph.user?$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/transitivemembers/microsoft.graph.user?$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled) eq true

For the filter to work, set the `ConsistencyLevel` header to `eventual.`

Let me know whether this helps, and if you have further questions.